# Setting an OnClickListenener in an ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android

I am trying to set an OnClickListener for a Textview in the getView() - Method of a class that extends ArrayAdapter. However, I can only click the first three items, after them I get a NullPointerException. Why?

**The Code:**

```
content = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_layout);
content.setText(currentLayout.getContent());

public View getView(final int position, @Nullable final View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    currentLayout = getItem(position);

    View view = convertView;

    if (view == null) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
    }

    content = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_layout);
    content.setText(currentLayout.getContent());

    number = view.findViewById(R.id.number);

    layout = view.findViewById(R.id.layout);

    content.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
        }
    });

    number.setText("1");

    return view;
}
```

**The Crash reprt:**

```
  --------- beginning of crash
08-10 15:18:45.591 3845-3845/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: com.example.philipp.einkaufsliste110, PID: 3845
                                                 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setBackgroundColor(int)' on a null object reference
                                                     at com.example.philipp.einkaufsliste110.Adapter.CustomAdapter$1.onClick(CustomAdapter.java:63)
                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
08-10 15:18:45.592 1651-2151/system_process W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.example.philipp.einkaufsliste110/.MainActivity
08-10 15:18:45.606 1305-3578/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property

                                                 [ 08-10 15:18:45.627  1651: 4136 D/         ]
                                                 HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x8e578440, tid 4136


                                                 [ 08-10 15:18:45.628  1651: 4136 W/         ]
                                                 Unrecognized GLES max version string in extensions: ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1
```

Comment: Show the stacktrace

Comment: Can you paste the exception

Comment: paste the exception to better help.

Comment: i did it. @VinceEmigh

Comment: didi it. @Swati

Comment: done @BrunoFerreira

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not checking null for convertview.

you only initialize view with convertview. but only initialize view if it is null but you do not initialize convertview if it is null.

Why can't you use view to set background instead of convertview?

You can use View holder as a better practice for the listview. refer -
 https://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

Also, you can do set the listener as below -

```
if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(/**layout file**/, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.content = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_layout);

        viewHolder.content.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
        });
        vi.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        // else code goes here
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();  
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. But what is a Viewholder?

Comment: You may want to look at the best practice to implement a ListView. Please visit the link mentioned in answer to look at the ViewHolder.